# \ttfamily is too bold for me

Tags: fonts, xetex, listings, bold, typewriter

I use the following settings for my listings:

```
\lstset{
  %basicstyle=\ttfamily\tiny, % small
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize, % middle
}
```

But the font in the listings is too bold for me. I tried a lot of things, but I couldn't change it.

I want to use a monospace (fixed) font in my listings, is there any other font  I could use?

PS: I compile my tex files with a xelatex compiler.

EDIT #2:

Complete example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,german,a4paper]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize, % bold and monospace
    %basicstyle=\scriptsize, % not bold and not monospace
}
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{lstlisting}
cntNodes++;
nodes = (DG_NODE_ID *) realloc(nodes, cntNodes * sizeof (DG_NODE_ID));
if (nodes == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: No memory left!\n");
    return false;
} /* if */
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Make a complete example so that we can see what you use as default typewriter.

Comment: Remove the packages xltxtra, lmodern, xunicode. Then make a *complete* example.

Comment: So now it is really complete, I ensured also that it compiles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

scale down the monospace font or use flexible colums or define a smaller letter space (see package fontspec). SourceCodePro is part of TL2012.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Calibri}
\setmonofont[Scale=0.95,
%             FakeStretch=0.8,
             Mapping=tex-text]{SourceCodePro-Regular.otf}
\newfontface\SmallMono[FakeStretch=0.8,
                       Mapping=tex-text]{SourceCodePro-Regular.otf}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\small, % middle
  columns=flexible
}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{lstlisting}
\directlua{securityproblem("\today")}
\end{lstlisting}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\SmallMono\small,
  columns=flexible}
\begin{lstlisting}
\directlua{securityproblem("\today")}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In PdfLatex I use a command `\newcommand*\lstfont{\ttfamily\hyphenchar\font\m@ne\@noligs}` to ensure that a proper minus sign "-" and not a rule is used (some fonts) in listings. How do I enforce the same thing in the example above? For example put `y = --x` in your source code and see the effect in the second listing.

Comment: @DanieEls: Simply don't use the `Mapping=tex-text` for the typewriter font.

Comment: or `literate={-}{{\char"02D}}1` with `\lstset`

Comment: So I just added following line: `\setmonofont[Scale=0.95]{SourceCodePro-Regular.otf}` and now it works for me.

Comment: One last question: What does the `columns=flexible` and `columns=fullflexible` settings exactly?

Comment: @Mej: The `listings` documentation has some examples

Comment: @Herbert Since you're not a chat regular, I'd like to congratulate you here for your big achievement: reaching 100k rep might not mean much (it does, indeed), but at least it gives an occasion for thanking you for your ***big*** contribution to the TeX world.

Answer (score 1):

If you put `\usepackage{times}` in your preamble, that will switch your monospace font to Courier, which is somewhat thinner than Computer Modern.

Alternatively, if you just put `\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}` in your preamble, that will switch your monospace font to Courier, but will not affect your other fonts.

You can also use `\lstset{basicstyle=\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont\scriptsize}` to change the font to Courier temporarily.

Comment: But if I use your package, my headers will be also displayed thinner. I just want to change the font in the listings. And the font will not be displayed in monospace.

Comment: If i just use: basicstyle=\scriptsize it is okay for me, but it isn't monospace.

Comment: This won't work with xelatex.

Comment: I added some more information in my initial post!

Comment: By loading the `times` package, you will also change the main text font from `Latin Modern` to `Times Roman` -- in addition to changing the monospaced font to `Courier`. The change to `Times Roman` text fonts may not be to the OP's liking.